# DMA transfert data

Tags: fpga, vhdl, dma

I have 2 image files imported by ENVI tool (png or raster file), and they are stored in my hard disk, I want to transfer this data from host PC to target FPGA using DMA (Data Memory Access). My questions are:

Is there a specific technique to transfer data to the target using DMA in FPGA? - I couldn't find any information on the internet.
Is there a technique to configure the FIFO as DMA? - In my case I need two DMA from host PC to target FPGA and one from FPGA to target.
At the end, there should be each image with a DMA and the third one to transfer from FPGA to host PC.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to use DMA with an FPGA is if the FPGA has a PCIe interface.  If your FPGA has high speed SERDES channels, the manufacturer usually supports some form of PCIe interface.

You can buy interfaces cards for PCs that allow you to have a cabled PCIe connection to your FPGA board, or you can design a card that plugs into the PCIe of the PC.